# Positioning UISearchBar above TableView in .xib

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar, xib

I'd like to make it easier for users to access the searchbar. Currently, the searchbar is above the tableview and when a user scrolls the tableview, the search bar scrolls off screen with it. Is there an easy way to position it above the tableview so it will always be visible?

I am using .xib files instead of the storyboard b/c I'd like my app to be compatible back to iOS 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you could do is just place a search bar above the table view in your XIB. Or just move the search bar you've (presumably) got in your table view's header view at the moment and put it above the table. You'll also have to shrink the table by 44 pixels (the height of the search bar) and move it down so that the search bar is above it.

If you go for deleting the one in the table view's header view and creating a new one then just make sure you hook it up correctly to whatever it is that's currently using it (i.e. probably an outlet for the search bar and its delegate).

Comment: Thanks. I'm a noob, been learning for a couple months, but only w/storyboards. I'd like to make my app compatible with iOS4.3 and 4.0 so I need to use nib files now, right? I originally posted this question b/c I was having trouble doing just what you said. If I tried to place the tableview 1st, I could not drop a tableview into my nib file without it taking up the whole view. If I tried to place the search bar 1st, I could not place a table view into the nib file afterwards without covering the search bar. I must be missing a simple detail.

Comment: Then place it and then resize it. Just drag the handles on the side or use the properties editor to edit the size manually.